# unique solution of an integral

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone help how can I solve the following?

Show that the integral equation

$f(t)=\int_{a}^{t} K(s)f(s)ds + \phi(t)$, $t\in[a,b]$

has a unique solution $f\in C_ \mathbb{R} [a,b]$, where $K(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ are two continuous real-valued functions on $[a,b]$.

*using the contraction mapping theorem.

Comment: You can use the fact the the integral and diffrential equations are equivelent (you use the fact taht you have diffrentiable functions) , and then you can use the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.

Comment: any other ideas of how to prove it using the contraction mapping theorem? sorry for not saying that before.

Comment: From what course you got this question? What theorems and tools do you have?

Comment: Every course has its own "mapping theorem"

Comment: Its a linear analysis course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using scaling, we may assume $\int_a^b|K(s)|ds< 1$. Define
$$T:C_\mathbb{R}[a,b]\to C_\mathbb{R}[a,b],\quad f(t)\mapsto\int_a^tK(s)f(s)dt+\phi(t)$$

Then note that

$$\Vert Tf-Tg\Vert_\infty\leq\Vert f-g\Vert_\infty\int_a^b|K(s)|ds=\theta\Vert f-g\Vert_\infty$$

where $\theta=\int_a^b|K(s)|ds\in[0,1)$. Thus by contraction mapping theorem $T$ has a unique fixed point.